# Eclipse to register new file type to appear as php code style?

Tags: php, eclipse, styles

I'm using Eclipse Helios on MacOSX. I'm PHP guy so i just want all PHP relateed scripts to be shown as PHP code style. I mean Code Colors.

What i'm having is: i'm developing Drupal on that Eclipse. I just wanna see php files in Drupal `.module` `.inc` `.install` .. whatever in future, as PHP style.

For example:
If i even make my own file extensions like `filename.abcd` later on, how if i what that `.abcd` extension files appear as PHP code style with colors?

Currently all of these **not previously registered extensions** are showing as just `Black Lines` with `no color`. How to do?

Comment: You need a [PHP-ready Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) if you don't have one already.

Comment: No. I found the answer now and accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure file associations under `Windows` > `Preferences`.
And under `General` > `Editors` > `File Associations`.

Simply associate the extension with the PHP Editor and it should pick up syntax highlighting for you.

For more information see:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-13.htm

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question (as I think it did) could you please mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Kepler and assigning the .module and .install file association did not work for me. (oddly enough, it did work for other extensions)   What did work was going to help > install new software and installing the software located at this url: http://xtnd.us/downloads/eclipse

found here: http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/using-eclipse-pdt-drupal-development